# Comparing two variables from different arrays in a foreach

Tags: php, variables, foreach

I am really new to PHP programming, and I'm frustrated because I think this should work and it doesn't. I'm really missing something...

```
<?php
foreach ($datas as $name)
    {
        if ($name['state'] === 'MA') 
        {
        echo
            '<input type="hidden" name="id" value="' . $name['id'] .     '" />' .
            '<h2>' . htmlentities($name['name']) . '</h2>' .
            '<p>' .
            htmlentities($name['description']) . ' ' .
```

...

```
'<h1>' . $name['id'] . '</h1>';

     foreach ($commentdatas as $name2)
     {
     if ($name['id'] == $name2['parkid'])
        {   
          echo $name['id'] . $name2['parkid'];
        }       
      }
}
}
?>
</div>
```

Everything worked well until I got to the second foreach statement. The `foreach works`. When I test, `$name['id']` echos properly, as does `$name2['parkid']`.

There doesn't seem to be a problem with the system correctly identifying these, even in the loop. `But inside the if statement, nothing echos at all.`

Obviously something is wrong with the if statement. I've looked everywhere I can find and I'm having trouble figuring out the proper way to compare these variables. Can anyone help?

Comment: Where does commentdatas came from? Is it a child of $datas ?

Comment: can you paste var_dump($name['id']) and $name2['parkid'] ?

Comment: Commentdatas is a different array.

Comment: can you paste var_dump($name['id']) and $name2['parkid'] ?

Comment: I did the var_dump and got exactly what I expected. It ran through each array..so I got 471472473474475, etc.

Comment: So, if I understand it right, I would think that when it gets to 4747 it will echo what I'm asking it to...right?

Comment: Wait...when I dropped the var_dump into the if statement (I thought I had the first time, but I am really struggling with simple stuff today) it returns nothing. It returned 471472473 OUTSIDE the if statement. Clearly it is my if statement that is the problem. I just don't know what to do about it.

Answer (score 1):

Try [in_array()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) function

```
foreach ($commentdatas as $name2)  {

     if ($name['id'] == $name2['parkid'])
        {   
          echo $name['id'] . $name2['parkid'];
        }       
      }
}
```

replace with

```
if(in_array($name['id'],$commentdatas)){

      echo $name['id'] . $name2['parkid'];      

}
```

Comment: I went to the link you provided to try to figure this out, and I'm just so new and learning it on my own that it made no sense. Can you give a simple English explanation as to what this does, so that I can do some more research on it?

Comment: I did more reading and I get it, but the two variables I am trying to compare are in two different arrays. I have foreach (first array) do stuff...then a second foreach (second array) if a specific variable from the first array matches a specific variable from the second array, then do stuff.

Comment: That replace with didn't return anything either.